# Set request parameter in Orbeon

Tags: eclipse, orbeon, xforms

I am very new to Orbeon and XForms.

I have created a form with input field "BaseId"

```
<xf:input id="control-3-control" bind="control-3-bind">
    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-3/label"/>
    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-3/hint"/>
    <xf:help ref="$form-resources/control-3/help"/>
    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
</xf:input>
```

and i want when i summit this form, in crud.xpl
method PUT i cant get value of BaseId through

```
<sql:param type="xs:string" select="/request/baseid"/>
```

Help me,please
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of controls are passed to the persistence layer REST API in an XML document, as the body of the HTTP request. So in `crud.xpl` (say [the one for eXist](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/persistence/exist/crud.xpl)), this will be a document under `/request/body`. The exact path depends on your section and control name. For instance, if the section is named `address` and the field `city`, the value will be under `/request/body/form/address/city`.

Comment: i 've changed my form same as your guide,my section name is "section" and my field is "baseid".
As your guide , in crud.xpl ( persistence mysql ) i will get value of "baseid" through <sql:param type="xs:string" select="/request/body/form/section/baseid"/> .But i can't get it here,it value is "null",so pls help me.

Comment: @LongHai It is hard to say exactly what is going wrong without running your code. I think you'll just need to debug this. For instance, try logging the `request` document to see exactly what it contains. You can do so by adding `debug="my request"` attribute to the `<p:output name="data" id="request"/>`. (The string `my request` is just there so you have something you can search for in the `orbeon.log`; you can set it to anything that is convenient for you to search.)

Comment: thanks,you saved me :D
but xpart is "/request/document/form/address/city" not "/request/body/form/address/city" (i realize it when i debug following your guide,thanks)

Comment: another question,i've created a new input field in **"dialog-form-setting"** .How can i get it value in crud.xpl when i saved this form.

Comment: @LongHai Ah, yes `document` not `body`; my fault! What do you mean by "created a new input field in dialog-form-setting"? You changed Form Builder's dialog where you set the app/form name? Where is that value stored? Do you store in the form metadata?

Comment: please see my question in this link [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228898/orbeon-how-can-i-pass-value-of-input-field-in-form-setting-to-crud)

Comment: @LongHai I answered that question, and apologize in advance if this isn't the answer you were looking for!